# Why is the refresh-token expiration not renewed in IdentityServer persistedgrants?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, identityserver4, refresh-token

I'm using .NET Core and IdentityServer4 for creating access-tokens. Those access tokens also include a refresh-token, which can be used to request new access-tokens. Since some users reported, that they get logged out too early I made a test in my local environment. I set the access-token-lifetime to 10 seconds, and the refresh-token lifetime to 30 seconds. The expected behaviour is, that you keep being logged in as long as you request a new token below 30 seconds. I then sent a request every few seconds. Every 10 seconds a new access-token is requested by the refresh-token. For this I use the Extension method "RequestRefreshTokenAsync". But this only works at max. 3 times:

```
04.12.2020 15:09:02 Using refresh token iCmtHJa5jllqTkwUexI9ZMLGN0RQhqvXljun6AgR31M.
04.12.2020 15:09:02 Success, new refresh token T0R8BWfNwkBzBh_yDKzhqerzgRgxY9OZ3jWLG951-hc.
04.12.2020 15:09:13 Using refresh token T0R8BWfNwkBzBh_yDKzhqerzgRgxY9OZ3jWLG951-hc.
04.12.2020 15:09:13 Success, new refresh token W29SlwHP318d4NFaqRS5ZTJAUG-ugYMBQrV6-g6v1rk.
04.12.2020 15:09:23 Using refresh token W29SlwHP318d4NFaqRS5ZTJAUG-ugYMBQrV6-g6v1rk.
04.12.2020 15:09:23 Error: invalid_grant
```

After I discovered this I also looked at the persistedgrants table of IdentityServer and it seems that for every refreshed access-token the same CreationTime and Expiration date is stored:

```
ocDMiwVpOJrcWh5LmEPgzDnn15TED5FpxSEpXsXDMzY= 2020-12-04 15:08:51.000000 2020-12-04 15:09:21.000000
i+NjVCnMUoobpnaINoLrCGcQrWHloIaAHC4NHWwGyK4= 2020-12-04 15:08:51.000000 2020-12-04 15:09:21.000000
d9HjtUszofxOEcnV7w95dhn54rl8QI2IRq8UMZlKr1Y= 2020-12-04 15:08:51.000000 2020-12-04 15:09:21.000000
```

What I would expect is, that when I request a new access-token, also the obviously new refresh-token gets a new expiration-date.

Does anybody know if I'm missing a specific setting or how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done to solve this is set your refresh token to have a sliding expiration. If you request a new access token before the sliding expiration then the refresh token expiration will be extended. This should be configurable in your identity server client settings. Check the docs here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. But then I noticed "The lifetime will not exceed AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime.". So this value was too low. As soon as I set it to the default (30 days) it worked. Thanks for your help and quick answer!